# R Data Analysis – Q3 Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System

Tags: linear-regression, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a data analysis project using the Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System (BRFSS) dataset in R. Specifically, I'm trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation for the variable MENTHLTH, comparing caregivers who managed personal care to those who did not.

Details:

Dataset: BRFSS
Variables: CRGVPERS (distinguishes caregivers from non-caregivers), MENTHLTH (number of days with poor mental health)
Value '88' in MENTHLTH represents 'None' (0 days)

Thanks in advance!

Expected Output: A dataframe (Q3) with two rows (caregivers and non-caregivers) containing mean_mental and sd_mental
CRGVPERS mean_mental sd_mental
1          1        5.23   [value]
2          2     [value]   [value]

Actual Output:
df <- brf %>%
mutate(MENTHLTH = ifelse(MENTHLTH == 88, 0, MENTHLTH))

## Step 2: Calculating Mean and Standard Deviation

## and Step 3: Creating the Dataframe

```
Q3 <- brf %>%`your text`
group by(CRGVPERS) %>%
summarize(mean_mental = round(mean(MENTHLTH, na.rm = TRUE), 2),
sd_mental = round(sd(MENTHLTH, na.rm = TRUE), 2))
```